# chromecast. from CDN - fling a URL to big screen

Tags: google-cast

Working with an existing CDN and with public URL's (H264 or WebM) i want to add to a current android consumer app the ability to show the ActionBar Icon for cast and to fling a URL at the TV for simple playback like you can do with Netflix or with Youtube content.

Do i need to write my own 'receiver' and publish that app? Do i just focus on the sender, altering my existing playback controller to add the actionBar icon so that when the cast icon on actionBar is clicked, it will simply provide the URL of the content to an EXISTING , generic receiver already on the cast device? That existing receiver would then handle the simple dialog chooser for the destination TV-device-id prior to starting playback.

I've looked quickly at some of the sample code on git. From that it looks like i do not even need a dedicated receiver in order to start playing content from my CDN on a big screen ( TV with chromecast ).

Comment: Please go to https://developers.google.com/cast/, most of your questions are answered there.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps   found answer in link.. May use a default receiver.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you need to write a sender, but not a Receiver.  We have a [Default Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#default) that can work with most non-encrypted content.  It is however, not branded.  If you'd like to include your brand, then you can use the [Styled Media Receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/styled_receiver).

On the other hand, if you use encryption, or have some other requirement not met by either the Styled Media Receiver or the Default Receiver, you can write a custom receiver.